# Why Would Application Variables Require Cookies at the Client Side?

Tags: cookies, iis-7, asp-classic, application-variables

I am updating a classic asp web application and looking at implementing application variables to save resources.

in the MS documentation, it mentions that "*Application and Session variables require that clients have cookies enabled*" (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300883)

I get why session variables would need that, but why would application variables require that?

Comment: Nice question. Just out of interest what makes you think you'll save resources using Application Variables? Surely storing values at the application level will use more resource not less??

Comment: They are more or less constants - objects which would be exactly the same for all users, such as site settings from a DB table. No need for every request to call to the db to get the settings, for example.

Comment: Don't overuse Application variables i tend to use `#include` files instead especially for constants.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Can you point me to some documentation or reasoning which supports your advice?

Comment: Apart from 10+ years of experience of working with Classic ASP?, no not off the top of my head. A lot of it is trial and error and finding out for yourself. Application Variables exist for the life of the Web Application so common sense dictates they will have a resource usage penalty. For example don't store COM references instantiate them as needed, especially `ADODB.Connection`. Instead use them to store configuration values like connection strings and instantiate the `ADODB.Connection` as needed. It is entirely up to you whether to follow this advice, good luck.

Comment: @Lankymart - completely agree with your example above. I was mainly going to use the application variable to store static site config settings, custom flag enums, etc. No COM objects for sure.

Comment: Then you have my blessing (not like you need it) ;-)